# What is the purpose of the "Other accounts you use" list in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, microsoft-account

What is the purpose of the "Other accounts you use" list in Windows 10 under "Settings - Accounts - Your account"?

Specifically, I have two Microsoft accounts and I'm often wanting to access online resources tied to the account that is not used to log in to the local PC. This leads to awkward logging in and out via a central web-based Microsoft login page.  How can this list help me?

[image: Screenshot from Settings in Win 10]

**Update:** In the "th2"/ 5011 / build 10586 update to Windows 10, they have  changed "Other accounts you use" to "Accounts used by other apps" which is a bit more informative.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what your talking about?

Comment: What actually happens if you add that 2nd account under "other accounts you use"?

Comment: @Ramhound Screenshot added.

Comment: @Techie007 I have added another account but I don't see what difference it made ... but nor do I know what to expect or look for!